# get resource owner name with HWIOAuthBundle

Tags: symfony, hwioauthbundle

I'm working on a website with the "Sign in with Twitter" and "facebook Connect" things. So far, I can connect with both, but I'm having trouble finding the resource owner's name. I followed danvbe guide to integrate these features [Great guide to implement Facebook Connect in a Symfony2 project](https://gist.github.com/danvbe/4476697), and found this line in the UserProvider :

```
$service = $response->getResourceOwner()->getName();
```

Obviously, I tried this simple condition :

```
if ($service == "facebook")
```

but it doesn't work. Any idea on how to get this name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nevermind, I found the solution ! To anyone wondering, you can use this :

```
    $service = $response->getResourceOwner()->getName();
    $user->setResourceowner($service);
    if($user->getResourceowner() === "[whatever you want, facebook, twitter, etc...]")
```

By doing so, you can access the resource owner anywhere.